# Best way to go about making custom, non-repeating border with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-dom

I'm working on a project where I think it would be really cool to add a customized, generated, non-repeating border to a post but I'm not sure about the best way to go about doing this.

I created a quick mockup in Inkscape of the idea (the border itself will be on all 4 sides of a rectangular div FYI):

[image: Grey rectangle background, black rectangle along the bottom edge, the top edge of the black rectangle has a series of diagonal white lines of slightly varying angles, and lengths]

What I want:

- Each line should go in the same direction with slightly varied angles
- Each line should be a different length within a range
- The midpoint of each line should be along the edge of the post
- The line should be generated not static so each border looks somewhat unique
- Should be able to draw the lines on all 4 sides
- Should work for different sized elements, posts will have different sizes depending on content and the solution shouldn't break if the size changes, obviously there will be bounds as to how big or small you can make it and still look good but a solution that scales is preferable
- Optionally I would like it to be as performant as possible but I can figure that out on my own

I've considered using an image for the background but I think that would be very janky since I'm looking for a dynamic solution and an image is static.
I've also considered using a canvas and drawing to it with JS, but it seems like the canvas element is meant to be, well a canvas, and not to decorate other HTML elements.

I do not need a perfectly working example I'm just not sure what direction I should go to make this happen or even if it's entirely feasible. Also as a side note, I'm looking for javascript implementations for now but I will eventually port this into a React app so if you have something that only really works with React that's also perfectly helpful

Comment: Not the solution you're looking for, but have you considered the CSS border-image property? It is highly customizable, rids you of the potentially long convoluted javascript code, and the image is barely a couple kilobytes big since you can repeat the same texture around the element. Check this example with proper documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Comment: @Code_Dummy00 I saw it while looking through options before posting here. The only problem I see with it is the pattern repeats, and it's static. So I could do top, bottom, left, and right and select from some presets using JS but I would end up with a lot of repeats, a lot of manual design work making the images, and a lot of images to serve. It's an option and I could make it work if there's nothing else but it just doesn't feel robust enough for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Alright here's a minimum reproducible code sample for a solution that kind of works

HTML:

```
<div id="Posts">
    <div class="post" id="post-1">
        <div class="canvas-container-border">
           <canvas ></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias sit ad dicta ea quidem dolores eum inventore fugiat aliquid doloribus unde tenetur libero aut maxime velit, mollitia reiciendis rem voluptatibus perspiciatis dolorem. Expedita praesentium eius qui ipsum temporibus voluptatibus similique explicabo dolores voluptates impedit? Voluptates velit dignissimos quisquam, expedita eaque id veritatis tempore nihil, recusandae voluptas saepe tenetur. Corrupti odio quasi minus sapiente repellat eaque, voluptatibus porro dolores, eveniet temporibus sit! Quisquam est, accusantium veniam ipsam reiciendis ducimus vel expedita, odit quae quam dolores id officia laborum. Pariatur et perferendis assumenda rerum non quisquam qui enim numquam animi maxime atque ab sunt cupiditate, illum nesciunt ad architecto distinctio tenetur adipisci! Eos excepturi nostrum ipsum voluptates hic quibusdam recusandae, vel mollitia, distinctio eaque, error nisi harum nemo rem! Ipsa, nemo sit nam, explicabo incidunt ut at porro harum numquam odio, natus assumenda itaque sapiente enim inventore dolor molestiae praesentium deleniti pariatur!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS: (this doesn't include most styling or any boilerplate, just the stylings that make this concept work)

```
$post-size: 40vw;

.post {
    display: grid; // make a grid that's just 1x1
    max-width: $post-size;
    height: fit-content;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;

    .canvas-container-border {
        display: inline-block;
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; // allows us to overlap canvas and post
    }

    .inner {
        width: fit-content;
        min-width: calc($post-size/2);
        height: fit-content;
        padding: 4em; // then use padding for spacing around the post

        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; 
    } 
}
```

JS (note default stroke color is white so if you're just copy pasting this into a blank page to see if it works set the color to something other than white or it'll blend in with the background

```
// get all the posts 
let posts = []

class post {
    constructor(el) {
        this.domElement= el;
        this.borderHeight;
        this.borderWidth;
        this.canvas = el.querySelector("canvas")
        this.id = el.getAttribute("id");

        this.resizeCanvas();
    }

    resizeCanvas() {
        let innerElement = this.domElement.querySelector(".canvas-container-border"); // the container the canvas is in already is the same size as the computed size of the post with padding
        this.borderWidth = innerElement.offsetWidth;
        this.borderHeight = innerElement.offsetHeight;   

        // then just set the canvas size so it covers the whole post
        this.canvas.height = this.borderHeight;
        this.canvas.width = this.borderWidth
    }

    clearCanvas() {
        // this just clears everything on the canvas so if we redraw we don't layer stitches on stitches
        this.canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

document.querySelectorAll("#Posts .post").forEach(el => {
    posts.push(new post(el))
})

function drawBorders(post) {
    // clear first
    post.clearCanvas()

    // consts for stitch gen
    const maxRise = 15; 
    const minRise = 10;
    const maxRun = 10;
    const minRun = 7.5; 

    const minSpacing = 12.5;
    const maxSpacing = 22.5;

    const maxOffset = 10;
    const minOffset = 0;

    const context = post.canvas.getContext("2d");

    // function to draw a line
    function drawStitch(ctx, x1, y1, rise, run, color = "white") {
        ctx.beginPath();

        // place the cursor from the point the line should be started 
        ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);

        // draw a line from current cursor position to the provided x,y coordinate
        ctx.lineTo(x1 + run, y1 + rise);

        // set strokecolor
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;

        // set lineWidth
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;

        // add stroke to the line 
        ctx.stroke();
    }


    // stitch func for top and bottom
    function stitchLine(ctx, startX, startY, length, horizontal=true) {
        let spacing = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxSpacing) + minSpacing;

        let cursorStart = horizontal ? startX: startY; //our x, y position tells us where to start, if we're horizontal we start at the x otherwise the y 

        for(let cursor = cursorStart; cursor < length; cursor+= spacing) {
            // calculate the rise (change in y), and run (change in x) as well as the offset (moves stitch in opposite direction of the line to create more variation looks more like handstitching)
            let rise = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRise) + minRise;
            let run = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRun) + minRun;
            let offset = (Math.random() * maxOffset) + minOffset;

            // if we're going horizontally we need to move along the x axis with the cursor and the y stays constant
            // opposite if we're not horizontal
            if(horizontal) {
                // context, x1, y1, rise, run
                drawStitch(ctx, cursor, startY + offset , rise, run)
            } else {
                // context, x1, y1, rise, run
                drawStitch(ctx, startX + offset,  cursor, rise, run)
                console.log(cursor)
            }
        }
        
        console.log("drawn")
    }

    // buffered values for lengths to prevent clipping
    const bufferedWidth = post.borderWidth - (maxSpacing);

    //inset values for start coords to prevent drawing offscreen
    const insetHeight = post.borderHeight - ((maxRise) + maxOffset);

    // offset values to re-center the border from buffering by using maxSpacing instead of 0 

    // horizontal lines

    stitchLine(context, maxSpacing, 0, bufferedWidth); // draw horizontal stitch line starting from top left to top right
    // we subtract the from the borderheight to prevent drawing off the canvas
    stitchLine(context, maxSpacing, insetHeight, bufferedWidth) // draw horizontal line starting at bottom left to bottom right


    // for the vertical lines we need to inset on both sides to prevent overlap with the top and bottom

    const overlapAllowance = 7.5; // allow some overlap to look more seamless

    const insetTop = (maxRise + maxOffset) - overlapAllowance; // inset top just needs to avoid the lowest down stitches
    const insetBottom = (post.borderHeight - (maxRise + maxOffset * 2)) + overlapAllowance; // the bottom stitches are already inset by maxRise + maxOffset so we need to offset by that much and then again to avoid collision 

    stitchLine(context, 0, insetTop, insetBottom, false)
    stitchLine(context, bufferedWidth, insetTop, insetBottom, false)

    // vertical lines

    stitchLine(context, )
}

window.onload = async () => {
    // draw all the borders on the posts
    setTimeout(() => {
        posts.forEach(post => {
            post.resizeCanvas()
            drawBorders(post)
        })
    },5) // for some reason this is the only way I could find to get the offsetHeight property to be accurate
}
```

I left out all my other page structuring and stuff but here's what my finished mockup looks like

[image: Social Media text post with lorem ipsum content, and a border that looks like hand done stitching around the outside]

In terms of performance I used the devtools to throttle my cpu 6x, enable advanced paint features, and set my hardware concurrency to 1, seems to take about 750ms - 1000ms to load so not amazing but not terrible, and I can implement some preloading in my actual project.

The only issue right now is it fits to the size of the post when the page loads but if the page resizes it doesn't resize the border, I tried to fix this with ResizeObserver but because that causes the element to resize when the canvas is cleared, then drawn on again it causes and infinite loop of clearing and redrawing the border while the element grows infinitely (not good). I'll update this when I have a working fix